# How to add a new block environment / layouts (definitions, theorem, etc) to RMarkdown beamer?

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, r-markdown, beamer

[image]I am trying to add insets (definitions, theorem, etc) to RMarkdown beamer.  Does anyone know how to do this?

An example would be a definition:

```
\begin_layout Definition
\begin_inset Quotes eld
\end_inset

[Cheese] cheese rocks. 
\begin_inset Quotes erd
\end_inset
```

Comment: @MrFlick is that clearer?  You know the kinds of layouts I'm referring to now yeah?

Comment: Yes. That makes it much more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a header level inferior to the slide level. Here is an example (which may look a little bit different with another beamer theme).

```
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: Copenhagen
    slide_level: 3
---

### Revenue management

#### Definition

Cheese rocks^[especially French cheese]
```

[image]